# Smart Device Link - Get Vehicle Data

Tags: android, ios, smartdevicelink

I took a look in the Smart Device Link library to Get Vehicle Data through vehicle communication using Smart Device Link (SDL).

The available parameters are shown in the links below, for android and iOS.

https://smartdevicelink.com/en/guides/iOS/getting-vehicle-data/

https://smartdevicelink.com/en/guides/android/getting-vehicle-data/

However, I noticed that there is no "Ethanol Fuel %" as an available parameter. This is an important information especially in the regions where more than one fuel is used in the vehicle and the change between them are frequent.

I haven't figure out other way to get in contact with SDL development team to raise that question. The only way I have seen in SDL website was to come to StackOverflow to raise questions.

So, the main point is:

1) As I know the information of "Ethanol Fuel %" is available in the CAN network in all the regions where Ethanol fuel is used because this information is mandatory by legislation

2) There is a OBD PID specific for this information: OBD PID 0x52.

Then, how can this information could be available through Smart Device Link?

The list of vehicle data parameters can be updated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am part of the team that maintains SmartDeviceLink. The best way to contact us is through our slack channel: http://slack.smartdevicelink.com

Adding additional vehicle data to the platform is possible, but it requires approval by the SmartDeviceLink consortium, the body that controls the development of the project. More about that process can be found in the readme here: https://github.com/smartdevicelink/sdl_evolution

You are also able to modify SDL core and the proxies as you wish, as it is open source but we highly recommend going through the process above so that others can also benefit from your addition.

Thanks for looking into the project

Comment: OK, I will try that way. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I didn't figure out how to get in contact through slack channel. How can I get an invitation to the SDL slack workspace?

Comment: Use the link above, It should auto approve you.

Comment: slack.  hmmmm.  A decidedly uninspiring name.  anyway ... I have the app (black) installed on my android phone and am in the smartdevicelink workspace but cannot figure out how to post a question.  I can see and search past posts fine.  How can I post a new question in slack?

Comment: @pdschuller it is essentially a messenger. you will want to add yourself to whatever channel best suits your question, for example `#android-help` and then simply post your question.

Comment: Ah.  I got it working.  Looks like everyone (including me) is in the #general channel at the outset.  What I didn't get is that, when viewing those messages, there is a box at the bottom of the screen that reads, "Message #general" and has some icons next to that.  You can tap that and enter your message for the #general channel.